# Remover item de lista

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-eventos, ecmascript-6

Como posso remover o item da lista que é gerado após o evento que o cria? Estou tentando colocar um evento que tem a função de remover o item, mas quando executo o código ele me volta um erro e o botão para remover não funciona.

```js
'use strict';
    
    //input do header
    const input = document.querySelector("input")
    
    //Botão do Header
    const headerBtn = document.querySelector("#btnHeader")
    
    //ul
    const list = document.querySelector("#list")
    
    //Class do botão de remover item
    const listBtn = document.querySelector(".btnList")
    
    //Função que cria um item no HTML
const model = (item) => {

    const itemList = document.createElement("li")

    itemList.innerHTML = `
        ${item}
        <button class="btnList">Remover</button>
    `

    list.appendChild(itemList)
}

  //Evento que cria o item ao clicar no botão
headerBtn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

    if(input.value === "" || input.value === " ") {
        alert("Preencha o campo com um item")

    } else {
        model(input.value)
        input.value = ""
    }
    
    event.preventDefault()
})

  //Evento que remove o item ao clicar no botão
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>To do list</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>
            To do List
        </h1>
    </header>

    <main>

    <section id="add">
        <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="O que deseja listar?" autocomplete="off">

            <button id="btnHeader">Adicionar</button>
        </form>
    </section>

    <section>

        <ul id="list">
        </ul>
        
    </section>

    </main>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Coloca no botão um `onclick="this.parentNode.outerHTML = ''"`. Isso vai remover a `<li>` onde está o botão.

Comment: No botão de remover? Mas eu também estou com o problema no evento de remoção, porque a li é gerada após a finalização do evento de criar, onde eu posso chamar esse evento?

Answer (score 0):

Em sua função `model(item)` você pode criar um elemento `button` para o botão "Remover", implementar o evento `onclick` e então adicioná-lo no elemento `li`. Por exemplo:

```
const model = (item) => {
    const itemList = document.createElement('li')

    itemList.innerHTML = item

    const btnRemover = document.createElement('button')
    btnRemover.innerText = 'Remover'
    btnRemover.onclick = function () {
      this.parentNode.remove()
    }

    itemList.appendChild(btnRemover)

    list.appendChild(itemList)
}
```

Exemplo funcional (adicionando o trecho no seu código):

```js
'use strict';
    
    //input do header
    const input = document.querySelector("input")
    
    //Botão do Header
    const headerBtn = document.querySelector("#btnHeader")
    
    //ul
    const list = document.querySelector("#list")
    
    //Class do botão de remover item
    const listBtn = document.querySelector(".btnList")
    
    //Função que cria um item no HTML
const model = (item) => {

    const itemList = document.createElement("li")

    itemList.innerHTML = item

    const btnRemover = document.createElement('button')
    btnRemover.innerText = 'Remover'
    btnRemover.onclick = function () {
        this.parentNode.remove()
    }

    itemList.appendChild(btnRemover)

    list.appendChild(itemList)
}

  //Evento que cria o item ao clicar no botão
headerBtn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

    if(input.value === "" || input.value === " ") {
        alert("Preencha o campo com um item")

    } else {
        model(input.value)
        input.value = ""
    }
    
    event.preventDefault()
})

  //Evento que remove o item ao clicar no botão
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>To do list</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>
            To do List
        </h1>
    </header>

    <main>

    <section id="add">
        <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="O que deseja listar?" autocomplete="off">

            <button id="btnHeader">Adicionar</button>
        </form>
    </section>

    <section>

        <ul id="list">
        </ul>
        
    </section>

    </main>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```